# nginx reverse proxy for Mikrotik.com

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

Hi we need to cache some site like [mikrotik](http://www.mikrotik.com) in our system but this site is use "HTTPS" protocol  and our caching system only cache HTTP protocol site So we thing if we used nginx as reverse proxy so client when visit https://www.mikrotik.com our DNS system well redirect to nginx local ip and nginx well fetch data from mikrotik as ***HTTP***  to client our problem is all thing is OK but if client visit any thing inside mikrotik webpage it well redirected to mikrotik original site .. this is sample of nginx config

```
server
{
    listen 80;
    server_name mikrotik.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://mikrotik.com/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is because all the links on the site will still be to https://mikrotik.com/... which you haven't proxied

You could try using the [Nginx sub filter](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html) module and rewrite all the links within Nginx before you serve them on your network. Adding some directives like this to your location block will get Nginx to rewrite the links from https to http on the fly:

```
location / {
    ....
    ....
    sub_filter_types text/html;
    sub_filter 'https://mikrotik.com/' 'http://mikrotik.com/';
    sub_filter_once off;
    sub_filter_last_modified on;
    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
```

I use this config for a similar purpose but the opposite way around, so going from http to https. Not sure if it will work for you in reverse as the whole point of SSL is to stop you doing this kind of thing, which is basically just a man in the middle attack